# Mysql benchamrking GUI tool

Tags: optimization, mysql, benchmarking, mysql-workbench

Hi
I need to optimize an application which is already there for a long time. Optimization will include move inline queries from php pages to "stored procedures", get rid of sub queries and convert them to "joins" etc etc.

I guess the best way is to use benchmarking tools for this purpose, but is there any GUI based tool available which I could use with Windows 7? Please help!

Also moving the inline queries to stored procedures and getting rid of sub queries, will that help in a major performance boost? Please feel free to express your opinion.

The major focus is on finding a suitable tool for benchmarking purposes however. Just a quick question will "Mysql workbench" help in this scenario? Pls advise.

Many thanks for your time in advance. Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the moving the inline queries to stored procedures. It really depends if you are going to use that query a lot or not. Switching from usign many queries to JOIN coudl be a major improvement in most cases, depends how much extra queries you were running initially.

As for benchmarking, well you can always use even phpMyAdmin to see how much time are takign certain queries and/or use a build in application benchmakring/profiling tool (even created from you PHP code) to bench the performance. This things usually do not have a straight and simple answer :(

Link with some suggestions http://beerpla.net/2008/04/16/mysql-conference-liveblogging-benchmarking-tools-wednesday-425pm/ maybe try WAST http://west-wind.com/presentations/webstress/webstress.htm

If you have a DB abstraction layer use it to log the performance of the queries and see if there are any that repeat too often or take too much time and also in which script they where called.